# Highchart Area Range chart with gradient that follows the line

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

The following is an Area Range chart which has a gradient.

http://jsfiddle.net/gXpHH/1/

What I want to do is have the gradient follow the curve, so that the color at any point along the bottom line is the same, and it ends at the same color when it reaches the top line.  I am pretty sure that this is not currently an option in highcharts, but I just wanted to see if anyone has run into this before.  Here is the code that currently generates the gradient:

```
series: [{
            name: "Shade",
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                stops: [
                    [0, "#4572A7"],
                    [1, "rgba(2,0,0,0)"]
                ]
            },
            data: [
                [0, 14733, 18890],
                [1, 16583, 21642],
                //... rest here
                [10, 42417, 61955]
            ]
    }]
```

Thanks

**Note**: this is not the same as [Gradient Fill on Line Chart (Highcharts)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10216654/gradient-fill-on-line-chart-highcharts) since I need the gradient to follow the curve

Comment: how can we use three colors as gradient lets say (Green, Yellow, and Red) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difficulty is the granularity: Highcharts draws one single SVG path for the series' points, and associates that one path with the gradient.
If your series data is relatively linear however, the following approximation might be useful.
See the [jsfiddle that I've created](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/7b7Bp/2/):

Assuming that your series data is not static, my demo includes two series and a function that, for each series, attempts to dynamically create the linearGradient that comes closest to your requirement:

```
function getLinearGradient(series) {
    var lastY0=null, lastY1=null, maxY0=null, maxY1=null;
    $.each(series.data, function(key,value) {
        maxY0 = Math.max(value[1],maxY0);
        maxY1 = Math.max(value[2],maxY1);
        lastY0 = value[1];
        lastY1 = value[2];
    });
    var firstY0 = series.data[0][2],
        firstY1 = series.data[0][2]
    ;
    var minY0=maxY0, minY1=maxY1;
    $.each(series.data, function(key,value) {
        minY0 = Math.min(value[1],minY0);
        minY1 = Math.min(value[2],minY1);
    });
    var minY = minY0,
        maxY = maxY1,
        heightY = maxY - minY
    ;        
    var gradient = {
            x1: 10 + ( ((firstY0-minY) / heightY) * 80 ) + "%",
            y1: "10%",
            x2: 10 + ( ((lastY1-minY) / heightY) * 80 ) + "%",
            y2: "90%"
    };
    return gradient;
};
```

Of course, this approach is not a full-blown solution and only useful if you're dealing with data that approximately follows a linear curve. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/7b7Bp/2/)

Comment: Well done!  Thanks for the answer, very interesting.  I may be able to use your solution here

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any example, nor do I know for sure if it is already in the specifications, but I am pretty sure the only way to accomplish this effect would be using svg mash gradients.

You could use the path points as boundary points for the mash matrix and get the effect you want.

See [here](http://www.svgopen.org/2011/papers/18-Advanced_Gradients_for_SVG/) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I haven't a clue how to implement this, but at least you have provided a potential solution.  I'm not sure I have enough time on this project to take this on, but at least this could help someone who does have the time.  I'll wait for a bit before marking any answer as the correct one.  Thanks again